# Transferring Storage Accounts Table into Data Lake using Data Factory

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to use Data Factory to transfer a table from Storage Accounts into Data Lake. Microsoft claims that one can, "store files of arbitrary sizes and formats into Data Lake". I use the online wizard and try to create a pipeline. Pipeline gets created, but I then always get an error saying:

Copy activity encountered a user error: ErrorCode=UserErrorTabularCopyBehaviorNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=CopyBehavior property is not supported if the source is tabular data source.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'.

Any suggestions what I can do to be able to use Data Factory to transfer data from Storage Accounts table into Data Lake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case is supported by ADF. While for the error you hit, there is a known defect that for some cases the copy wizard mis-generate a "CopyBehavior" property which is not applicable. We are fixing that now.

For you to workaround, go to Azure portal -> Author and deploy -> select that pipeline -> find the "CopyBehavior": "MergeFiles" under AzureDataLakeStoreSink and remove that line -> then deploy and rerun the activity.

If you happened to author an run-once pipeline, please re-author a scheduled one given the former is hard to be updated using JSON.

Thanks,
Linda